# The extinction coefficients of oxymyoglobin and ferryl myoglobin

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I want to know what the extinction coefficients of oxymyoglobin and ferryl myoglobin are. I was able to find the one for the oxymyoglobin in [this](https://doi.org/10.1021/bi00591a020) pretty old article (it says that it equals $121 \text{mM}^{-1}\text{cm}^{-1}$), but I couldn't locate any other reference supporting this claim. Furthermore, I couldn't find any reference in the case of ferryl myoglobin.

I am also curious if, in general, there are tables containing the extinction coeffcients of various compounds (at different wavelengths).

Comment: Which organism are you interested in? They will be very similar among mammals, but not identical. Also, for which wavelength do you want to know it?

Comment: @Karsten I am interested in horse heart Mb and I want to know it for the absorption maximum, so somewhere around 410-425 nm for the Soret band.

Comment: Which pH are you interested in?

Comment: @Karsten I am interested in pH 9.